# Making a bash script to compile / execute C++

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to make a simple script that will compile test.cpp but I cannot get it to work. I'm running the script like this:

```
> bash make.sh
```

And getting the following error:

```
: No such file or directory
g++: no input files
make.sh: line 3: ./test.out: No such file or directory
```

Here is make.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
g++ -o ./test.out ./test.cpp
./test.out
```

I've tried it without the " ./ " and it still doesn't work. I am running Cygwin on Windows 7 with all the proper packages installed (I can compile and run from the shell itself, just not from script).

Comment: Replace ./ with absolute path! For Example: /home/MyName/test.cpp

Comment: You need to run this in the same directory.

Comment: what are the permissions on the script file? is the execute bit turned on?

Answer (score 2):

Did you create `make.sh` with Notepad?  If so, every line ends with a `CR` (carriage return) and a `LF` (line feed).  Cygwin and its Unix-like programs cannot handle that; Unix expects lines in text files to end with just a `LF` (which Unix calls a “new line” character).  Edit your file with a Cygwin editor (e.g., `vi` or `vim`) and fix it.  If you cannot do that, try adding “`; #`” to the end of each line; that should cause `bash` to treat the offending `CR`s as comments.

To expand on the above: if my theory is correct, the second line of `make.sh` looks like:

> `g++ -o ./test.out ./test.cpp`<kbd>CR</kbd>

plus the `LF` that’s supposed to be there (that `bash` excludes from consideration).  So, `g++` is looking for a file whose name is “`./test.cpp`<kbd>CR</kbd>”, which, of course, doesn’t exist. 
So it says:

> `./test.cpp`<kbd>CR</kbd>`: No such file or directory`

But, because of what a carriage return is, this causes the `: No such file or directory` to overwrite the `./test.cpp`, so `: No such file or directory` is all you see.